# Absolute jump in masm

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I use - masm `6.11` and I'm trying to do absolute jump to address `0x1200` and I can not.
I try to do so:
`jmp fword 000h: 1200h` and I'm trying to get the assembled equivalent of this:

```
EA 12 00 00 00
```

What to change to get the same binary?

Comment: What do you get instead?

Answer (score 0):

Little endian values are: low high low high

```
EA 12 00 00 00   jmp 0000:0012
EA 00 12 00 00   jmp 0000:1200
```

Dirk